# PendingIntent issue with Notification

Tags: kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

Working through somebody else's code and trying to establish what's missing to make the notification work in this specific instance. Notifications are received fine in the foreground and background through the *MainActivity* class. Launch mode is set to ***singleTop*** to avoid more than one instance of the class.

However, when I'm in the app and hit screen lock and proceed to send a notification, the device wakes up, the notification is received, the intent is received through *onNewIntent* but none of the Notification data is available in the intent. What's missing?

Just to reiterate if I put the app in the background and hit screen lock there's **no** issues and the intent is loaded with the notification data (not through *onNewIntent*).

Answer (score 0):

ok so the data was present in the intent. Even with the debugger on I had missed it but sure enough it is there ...

```
 override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    val data = intent?.extras
    if (data != null) {
        for (key in data.keySet()) {
```